# Inserting data through form fields into the Berkeleys db with python

Tags: python, database, berkeley-db, bsddb

I have a form with FirstName, LastName, Age and Gender. Now How do i insert data into the Berkeley db with python ? I am really new to this kinda database.
Most database have the sql queries to associate and a cursor to get and fetch data. But in case of Berkeley there is no such.

I have reading about Berkeleys db, but i am not getting it. Any ones help is appreciated

I am using Python 2.5

How can i Integrate this data which comming from form into Berkeley db ??

Theres some error comming when i run on server:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/bsddb/__init__.py", line 306, in hashopen, referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181]     , referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] d.open(file, db.DB_HASH,     flags, mode), referer: http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] bsddb.db, referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] ., referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] DBAccessError, referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] : , referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] (13, 'Permission denied'),     referer: http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] , referer:     http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
[Fri Nov 08 17:26:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.2.181] Premature end of script     headers: database.py, referer: http://192.168.2.181/~jeremy/index.html
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import bsddb
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

Fname = form.getvalue('firdtname')
Lname = form.getvalue('lastname')
Age = form.getvalue('age')
Gender = form.getvalue('gender')

db = bsddb.hashopen("/tmp/mydb.db","c")
db['FirstName'] = Fname
db['Lastname'] = Lname
db['Age'] = Age
db['Gender'] = Gender

db = bsddb.hashopen("/tmp/mydb.db")

print db['FirstName'], db['Lastname'], db['Age'], db['Gender']

db.close()

print "Content-type:text/html\n"
```

Comment: What version Python are you using?

Comment: BDB is a keystore. You don't want a keystore.

Comment: Yes it stores the key value pair like hashtables. But how do i simply insert data in to berkeley db ?

Comment: You don't "simply" insert it. You *complexly* insert it. Which is why you don't want it.

Comment: Ok. But how would i insert data into it ? Lets all forget upon all the above description. And let me know how do i insert data in term of key value in berkeley db

Comment: *sigh* [Bsddb objects behave generally like dictionaries. Keys and values must be strings, however, so to use other objects as keys or to store other kinds of objects the user must serialize them somehow, typically using marshal.dumps() or pickle.dumps().](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html#module-bsddb)

Comment: so comming upon the above description of adding data from form .How do i achieve that ?

Comment: Anyone can help would be great to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read and write to it exactly like a dictionary.

```
>>> import bsddb
>>> db = bsddb.hashopen('mydb.db')
>>> db['FirstName'] = 'Joe'
>>> db['LastName'] = 'Doe'
>>> db['Age'] = '30'
>>> db.close()
>>> 
>>> db = bsddb.hashopen('mydb.db')
>>> db['FirstName']
'Joe'
```

However, Berkeley DB stores only pairs of key/value strings, so maybe that's not what you really need if you want to store those values for several different entries. If no other language will be using that db file, maybe you can use the shelve module to store pickled dicts. If you need it to be easy for others to use, you could serialize your form data as json. Something like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> import bsddb
>>> db = bsddb.hashopen('mydb.db')
>>> form = {'FirstName': 'Joe', 'LastName': 'Doe', 'Age': 30}
>>> db['joedoe'] = json.dumps(form)
>>> db.close()
>>> 
>>> db = bsddb.hashopen('mydb.db')
>>> json.loads(db['joedoe'])
{'FirstName': 'Joe', 'LastName': 'Doe', 'Age': 30}
```

But frankly, this starts to look more and more like an anti-pattern, and unless you're absolutely restricted to using Berkeley DB for some reason, you shouldn't be doing it that way. You should be using sqlite for that.

Comment: I have done this prograaming using a text file, where user can add all there data into the text file. Now i want the same i.e. the data to be integrated into the berkeley db.

Comment: How do i achieve the same using Berkeley db ?

Comment: That example is using Berkeley DB. mydb.db is a hash db file.

Comment: What if I have multiple data records. Using this i wont be able to store data line by line and display the whole record of a person

Comment: Hence my last phrase, Berkeley DB is probably not what you need. You can store pickled dictionaries as values, but you'd be better using the shelve module, which already uses Berkely DB as engine.

Comment: Look i have updated my code. I want that all to integrate into the Berkeley db ? how can i do that ? If you say using Shelve module, could you please show some snippet to how do i do it ?

Comment: I have been instructed to use only Berkeley db. Take the values from the form and insert it into Berkeleys db, so i am really confused to how should i do that ? or to where to i start from ?"

Comment: Also here the data in the code hardcore. the data should dynamically come from the form .

Comment: This is starting to look more and more like homework assignment. The above information should be more than enough for you to figure it out. Have fun.

Comment: Its not an homework. i have been been doing myself with an some help from my senior

Comment: If it's not homework, you're doing it wrong. You shouldn't use Berkeley DB for that.

Comment: I am using Berkeley db b'coz i dnt have any other database installed in my linux oS. Your help would be appreciated if you wish

Comment: Updated an Berkely db updated code with error_log. wahts the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

[Python Docs Berkeley- see 'put'](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/db.html#put)

```
#include <db.h>

int
DB->put(DB *db,
    DB_TXN *txnid, DBT *key, DBT *data, u_int32_t flags);
```

The DB->put() method stores key/data pairs in the database. The default behavior of the DB->put() function is to enter the new key/data pair, replacing any previously existing key if duplicates are disallowed, or adding a duplicate data item if duplicates are allowed. If the database supports duplicates, the DB->put() method adds the new data value at the end of the duplicate set. If the database supports sorted duplicates, the new data value is inserted at the correct sorted location.

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_03/html/api_reference/C/dbput.html)

Comment: Aww. I want in the pythonic way brother

Comment: @user2968229 As the link Ignacio showed, it's deprecated. This link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb3/ provides the Python Interface for Berk DB.

Comment: I have python 2.5.1 version installed. so bsddb3 wont be imported

Comment: This should help. Python 2.5.1 does
> not come with any bsddb version whatsoever https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-November/456439.html

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html#module-bsddb - This link code seems to be working fine in my python version